# How do I transfer a file over ssh from one machine to another?

Tags: ssh, file-transfer

My professor wants us to email him source files, but he wants us to edit over ssh using vi. How do I transfer a file over ssh from one machine to another?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To transfer a file over ssh you should use the `scp` command.

Basic usage is :

```
[you@localhost ~]$ scp examplefile yourusername@remoteserver:/home/yourusername/
```

It will copy over SSH the file `examplefile` to the remote server at the location `/home/yourusername/examplefile`

More concrete example :

```
[Moshe@localhost ~/mywork]$ scp thework.zip Moshe@192.168.1.21:/home/Moshe/
```

Where it is assumed your **local** file is `/home/Moshe/mywork/thework.zip` and you have permission to login to the server 192.168.1.21 and to write in the **remote** directory `/home/Moshe`

You will end with the file copied under `/home/Moshe/thework.zip` on the **remote** server.

If you are not working under Linux or any Unix-based system locally (ie. you're on Windows typically), a tool like WinSCP will enable you to transfer the file over SSH with help of a graphical interface.

Comment: @Zertin - I have a .tar.gz file on one remote server. Can I unzip and untar the file in one go and copy the file from one server to another?